# How to get php $_SESSION variable inside a template

Tags: civicontribute, templates, smarty

I am setting `$_SESSION` variable inside a payment response file and need this to display on Thank you page. Somehow nothing seems to work so far.

Tried following things:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Hello World'; // Inside payment response file
```

Need this in `confirm.tpl` file. Tried

```
{$session->get('test') // does not work
{$smarty.session.test} // does not work
```

Tried so many other things but nothing seems to work. Also, it's not working for any other variable like `$_SERVER`, `$_POST` etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
    Try following:

    // php code;
        $_SESSION['test'] = 'Hello World';

    // assign 'Hello World' to .tpl
        $this->assign('test', $_SESSION['test']);

    // use '{$test}' following in .tpl file to display on Thank you page, For e.g
       <tr>
         <td>{$test}</td> // this will print 'Hello World' on page
       </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan but it's not working.